# Run service after killing from background in all android devices

Tags: android

I want a service to run always in background so that I can receive notifications always, also after removing the app from task manager by swipping out

Comment: use AlarmManager and PendingIntetnt

Comment: I have used those stuffs but when I remove the app from background the service is also getting stopped..I have used return STICKY also..Dont know where I am missing some lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button but_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_Start);
        but_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MyService.class);
                startService(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started in" +
                " a Different " +
                "Process", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //stopSelf();//force service to a stop.
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but_Start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Start Service" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text= "Start Service in a Different Process"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.start_service_diff_process"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.start_service_diff_process.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":my_process" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i implemented the code but when i remove the app from task manager then its not showing in "Apps running" tray of my phone android 5.1....Am I leaving something as i have done exactly you have specified

Answer (score 0):

When you remove app from task manager it ends process and your service is running in that process. You have to run service in different process. you can do it in manifest file

```
<service 
    . . .
         android:process="string" >
</service>
```

Comment: can you a give an example as I am a newbie in android

Comment: i already gave you example in Manifest.xml file add process attribute in service tag

Comment: also check this tutorial about services http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: can you a give me sample source code for that @Kamran

Answer (score 0):

Service itself running in background and it doesn't matter if you close your app or not.

If you want more detail

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html